# Excel.exe app not closing when finished using it

Tags: c#, excel, com

I am currently trying to email the graph/chart from a .xls as an image.
I can get the graph/chart send the email fine.
My issue is when i look in the task manager there is a "EXCEL.EXE" still running after i have called `xlApp.quit()`

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code i am currently using.

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbooks xlBooks;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.ChartObject xlChartObject;
Excel.Chart xlChart;

object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
xlWorkBook = xlBooks.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.FileToSend);
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

xlWorkSheet.EnablePivotTable = true; 
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

xlChartObject = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(1);
xlChart = xlChartObject.Chart;
xlChart.Export(filename + ".gif");

xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
xlBooks.Close();
xlApp.Application.Quit();

if (xlChart != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlChart); xlChart = null;

if (xlChartObject != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlChartObject); xlChartObject = null;

if (xlWorkSheet != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet); xlWorkSheet = null;

if (xlWorkBook != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook); xlWorkBook = null;

if (xlBooks != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBooks); xlBooks = null;

if (xlApp != null)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp); xlApp = null;

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Ok have edited my code and still not closing excel.
It does however die when i exit the program.

Thanks

Comment: `xlApp.Workbooks.Add` - as follow up from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects/158752#158752) - `Never use 2 dots with com objects.`

Comment: Ok i removed all 2 dots

Comment: I always implement IDisposable and make a call to GC.COllect in my Dispose method if something is still hanging. Excel can be a pain sometimes

Comment: @mehow Can you give me an example?
Does not IDisposable just wrap it with a try/catch?

Comment: I can't find my SO answer but [here's pretty much a copy](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/c-and-vba/using-net-connection-string-attributes-in-vba-via-com-library/). I have had a problem with the adodb.connection hanging because Excels garbage collector didn't clear the com resources right away therefore I implemented IDisposable interface and just cleared resources in there, it turned out to be as simple as `cn = null` other stuff was taken care off already. I realize it's a bit different example here but instead of all those if statements that's how I'd go about it

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I have answered my own question, just cant accept it till tomorrow :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay finally!

Got it working.

I added

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

out of the function that i was using EXCEL.

```
private void runExcelWork()
{
   //xlApp, xlBooks, xlWorksheet etc.. Is defined in this function
   //Do your work with Excel here.
   //Clean all excel objects here.
}

public void runExcel()
{
   runExcelWork();
   //call GC
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   GC.Collect();
   //at this point EXCEL.EXE closes
}
```

Thank you to all who helped me with this issue!

I hope someone else finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to free every object that you use.

It seems that `xlApp.Workbooks` is used by is not freed.

As a side note, it could also be that there was an exception and thus your cleanup code was missed.

Try something using a `try/catch/finally` like the following:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = null;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

try
{
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
    xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.FileToSend);
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

    xlWorkSheet.EnablePivotTable = true; 
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export(filename + ".gif");

    xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // handle error...
}
finally
{
    if (xlWorkSheet != null)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);

    if (xlWorkBook != null)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);

    if (xlWorkBooks != null)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks);

    if (xlApp != null)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, have a look at what i am using now

Comment: I did, it gave me an error saying xlApp was not in scope

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a second gc.collect after.

```
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();   //gc calls finalize on objects
                GC.Collect();                    //collect objects just finalized
```

mehow mentioned implementing IDisposable. I would recommend this as well.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something along the lines of:

```
 xlWorkBook.Close();
 xlApp.Application.Quit(false);
 xlApp = null;
```

This should clean up any remaining `excel.exe`  processes

You could try to kill the process directly. (Processname could be in capital letters)

```
try
{
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("excel"))
    {
     process.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, have a look at what i am using now

Comment: You kill the process directly (i've adjusted my code)

Comment: Downvoted because this is not the best way to stop Excel when using COM. The reason is because there are still COM objects in memory. What if the user is using Excel for another purpose?

Comment: Is my personal opinion aswell. But if nothing else works that (the first bit of code `always` works with me), its sometimes necessary to use crude methods.